# How to change the fill of an object in a JavaFX Animation?

Tags: animation, javafx

I'm developing a simple Java videogame. I've decided to shape the characters of that videogame by using the `Rectangle` class of JavaFX.

When a character dies, I need to update the texture sequentially, until the death of the characters. I need to realize an animation for this reason.

I've tried to use the `FillTransition`, but I can't change the filling Image of the rectangle but only the color...what kind of animation class should I use?

The death of a character is represented by 4 different sprites (four png images) which shows the character laying down to the soil gradually. I need to change the filling of the rectangle with these 4 images sequentially, while the character is dying.

Comment: Depends on the kind of animation you need. Please add a description of the desired result to the question. Are you using a spritesheet or different images or something like this?

Comment: The death of a character is represented by 4 different sprites  (four png images) which shows the character laying down to the soil gradually...I need to change the filling of the rectangle with these 4 images sequentially, while the character is going to die...i don't know if I've explained the problem...

Answer (score 0):

`Rectangle` is not a good node type to do this kind of stuff. It's much simpler to use `ImageView` for this purpose.

This allows you do use a `Timeline` for manipulation of the `image` property of the `ImageView`:

```
final Image[] deathAnimationImages = new Image[] {...};

final ImageView character = ...;

Duration frameDuration = Duration.seconds(1d / deathAnimationImages.length); // 1 second for complete animation
Timeline deathAnimation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(frameDuration, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    private int index = 0;    

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        character.setImage(deathAnimationImages[index]);
        index++;
    }
}));
deathAnimation.setCycleCount(deathAnimationImages.length);
deathAnimation.play();
```

If you use `Rectangle` + `ImagePattern` to get a image of a given size you can produce the same result using `ImageView.fitWidth` and `ImageView.fitHeight`.